# Silverlight 4 : TreeView/ HierarchicalDataTemplate/ AutoExpand Issue

Tags: .net, silverlight, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a treeview control in my silverlight application which uses 2 HierarchicalDataTemplate(s) to show data in a rquired format. I would like to have this tree autoexpanded when open for first time (preferably, a code snippet which i may call any time i want).

Any alternatives to the given code would also be welcome.

```
<sdk:TreeView x:Name="tvPageManager" Style="{StaticResource PageManagerStyle}"                                       
                        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                            <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding KeyPoints, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                        <ToolTip Content="{Binding PageName}" Style="{StaticResource ToolTipStyle}"/>
                                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                    <Image x:Name="imgPageIcon" Source="{Binding PageIconImage}" Style="{StaticResource PageIconStyle}" Tag="{Binding BurstPageId, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="tbkLiteralTextPage" Text="Page " Style="{StaticResource PageNameLiteralTextBlockStyle}" />
                                    <TextBox x:Name="tbPageName" Text="{Binding PageName, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource PageNameTextBoxStyle}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Image x:Name="imgKeypointIcon" Source="../Assets/Images/bullet_yellow.png" Style="{StaticResource KeypointIconStyle}"/>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="tbkKeypointTitle" Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource KeypointNameTextBlockStyle}"  />
                                            <StackPanel x:Name="spnlMoveImages" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="30">
                                                <Image x:Name="imgMoveUp" Source="../Assets/Images/up_arrow.png" Style="{StaticResource MoveIconsStyle}" Tag="{Binding KeyPointId}"/>
                                                <Image x:Name="imgMoveDn" Source="../Assets/Images/down_arrow.png" Style="{StaticResource MoveIconsStyle}" Tag="{Binding KeyPointId}"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                            </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        </sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    </sdk:TreeView>
```

This control is bound to a Observable list of BurstPage class. The complete data structure is as;

The parent element is Burst object which contains 1 to n BurstPage objects, Any given BurstPage may have 1 to n Keypoint objects in it.

BurstPage.Name (say 1)
     Keypoint.Name (say A)
     Keypoint.Name (say B)
     Keypoint.Name (say C)
BurstPage.Name (say 2)
BurstPage.Name (say 3)
     Keypoint.Name (say D)
     Keypoint.Name (say E)

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling there is a lot of code missing from your post...

But I think you might find the following useful: [one-more-platform-difference-more-or-less-tamed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/05/07/one-more-platform-difference-more-or-less-tamed-settervaluebindinghelper-makes-silverlight-setters-better.aspx)

It has some good pointers on how you can bind controls like the treeview, and work with them in code.

Comment: Thanx Anders, i have updated the XAML. Please have a look now.

Comment: Okay, I would think that you could definitely use the methods in the link I posted to bind the TreeViewItem's IsExpanded property to a property in your bound data objects.
Are you following the MVVM pattern?

Comment: I found a simpler solution to the auto expand;

    `<UserControl.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="sdk:TreeViewItem">
          <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
     </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>`

Comment: Sure, if you only want the tree expanded initially, that's an easy way to do it. I'm sorry if I misunderstood your needs :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, that XAML will only expand the tree initially, while adding new nodes i use;

```
private void ExpandNode()
{
    if (branchSelector < 1)
        return;

    TreeViewItem item = null;
    int itemAtIndex = 0;

    //Update tree layout
    this.tvName.UpdateLayout();

    foreach (var branch in this.tvName.Items)
    {
        item = (this.tvName.GetContainerFromItem(this.tvName.Items[itemAtIndex]) as TreeViewItem);
        if (item != null && item.HasItems)
        {
            if ((branch as Model.BranchBusinessObject).Id== branchSelector && (!item.IsExpanded))
                item.IsExpanded = true;
        }
        itemAtIndex++;
    }
}
```